# How to use exec() on Windows with MSVC++?

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, porting

I am attempting to port a Fortran-C code that was written for POSIX to Windows. From what I can see, the majority of the program can be compiled on Windows, only a few small commands have to be changed.

In the fortran part of the program, there is a line

```
call system("exec xmrcc >> output.log")
```

The problem is that, windows does not have any `exec` command. However, after some digging, I found that on linux the `exec` command uses the underlying `execvp()` call. On Windows, MSVC++ provides `_exec()` and the family of related functions.  The `_execlp()` or `_execlpe()` seems to be those that I want.

So, I want to replace the fortran system call with a C function that will wrap around the `execlpe()` and call the program xmrcc.exe.

However, I cannot figure out how the functions work! I have read [Microsoft documentation on exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/exec-wexec-functions?view=msvc-160), [Use of execl (Arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245178/use-of-execl-arguments), and [C- Using exec() in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679058/c-using-exec-in-windows) . After following the accepted answer of the last question linked, I wrote this C code to test `_execlp()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

int main()
{
    printf("started running");
    _execlp("C::\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\CMD.EXE", "cmd.exe", "/c",
 "echo", "foo",">G:\\Python\\foo.txt");
}
```

However, on running the compiled code, I only got the output "started running" and then it returned; there was no foo.txt file in G:\Python. Then I thought maybe the output redirection is causing problems, so I removed it:

```
    _execlp("C::\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\CMD.EXE", "cmd.exe", "/c", "echo", "foo");
```

Still nothing. It only prints "started running", it does not print "foo".

I have two main questions:

1. **How do I properly run `_execlp()` on Windows?** (to run xmrcc.exe and direct the output to log)
2. **Is it necessary to use the `_execlpe()` to pass the enviornment variables?** (I don't understand how this works.)

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ v19 compiler.

[Please don't mention cygwin, or mingw or WSL, they are not what I am looking for. And I know that system calls in fortran are discouraged, but I didn't write the program, I am only porting it.

And I need to use `_execlp()` because it replaces the calling process with the child process entirely, and is the closest to linux `exec` command. This is necessary, because other parts of the program use PIDS, so it's necessary that the a child process with a different PID is not spawned.]

Edit: Would removing the exec shell command work? as in `call system("xmrcc >> output.log)` It was suggested in the comments by @ChrisDodd.

Comment: The `exec` here is the `exec` shell builtin, not the exec system call (system calls have nothing to do with the system library function).  You can do the same thing by just removing it -- eg use `system("xmrcc >> output.log")`

Comment: Use `CreateProcess`.

Comment: @IInspectable Does CreateProcess() handle PIDs? I need the PIDs to remain the same.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I understand that the exec is the shell command. If I just remove it, wouldn't it create a new process? I thought exec command replaces the calling process with the child process entirely, i.e. when xmrcc ends, shell does not return.

Comment: `CreateProcess` returns - among others - the PID of the process created. Though a PID is largely useless, since you have no way of knowing whether any given value still refers to the same process. Hardly surprising, since most everything POSIX is fairly useless in context of an OS that is far more advanced than what POSIX attempts to capture (essentially 60s technology).

Comment: `system` will create a new shell process and wait for it.  With `exec`, the shell will replace itself with xmrcc; without it, it will run xmrcc as a child.  In either case when xmrcc exits, the system function will return.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to fix:

1. the colon ':' after 'C' should not be doubled
2. _execlp expects a null in the parameter list to detect that there are no more parameters.

So this works:

`_execlp("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\cmd.EXE", "cmd.exe", "/c", "echo", "baz", ">c:\\test\\bar.txt", nullptr);`

Comment: Also, do I need to pass the environment variables ? Are they required for the program to work?

Comment: If you use _execlp, there is no way to pass environment variables separately. The child process will inherit the environment variables of the launching one.